# AvAudioRecorder on cancel replace old Audio files

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am using AvAudio Recorder for record Audios in IOS app and save in document directory but when i record a audio file and then again going for new recording and during recording  click on cancel button (manually added) the previous file is replacing please suggest any answer

Thanks in advance

Comment: did u save audio file with same name?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSString *) dateString
{
// return a formatted string for a file name
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"ddMMMYY_hhmmssa";
return [[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] stringByAppendingString:@".aif"];
}
```

save with date and time
like this

```
NSArray *searchPaths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath_ = [searchPaths objectAtIndex: 0];

NSString *pathToSave = [documentPath_ stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self dateString]];

// File URL
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToSave];//FILEPATH];
```

Comment: Thanks for replay but i am not using like this type logic.

Comment: When user add one audio it is saving in path like : audio.mp3
After that when user again start recording for new audio i am replacing old file to this new file.
But in this case if user cancel recording then old file is replacing